# Working with C# ASP.NET ListView, Unable to return DisplayIndex

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview

During my research I have found some solutions to my problem (described below) but unfortunately these solutions will not work for Websites since they are all targetting WinForms.

I need to get the DisplayIndex of a ListViewItem on a MouseOver event. I don't want to do stuff like add the index when the page is rendering via a custom html attribute like `'index="0"'` and then use that in my `__doPostBack()` function.

I have an `updatepanel` and a `listview` inside of it all within an absolute div, when the mouse is over a Label located in another `listview` item, I'd like to be able to update the `updatepane`l with the data relevant to the item that's hovered. The whole idea behind this is that I want to use a single container div and hide/show it on each `mouseover` on the `listview` items.

So basically, when mouseover let's say a label with an ID="hi" inside a listviewitem inside listview id="lv" I want to get that listviewitem ID to update another listview inside another updatepanel.

I'm not sure if this is all confusing but just getting the `DisplayIndex` of a hovered `listviewitem` and using that in a `__doPostBack` function will solve my issue.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you arbitrarily reject good solutions like using a custom html attribute `index=#`?

Comment: is it considered good practice to do that? I find it a bit messy. I'm sure there's another way of doing this :/

Comment: Sure, if it gets the job done :)  I don't see any problem with it.  If you truly wanted to avoid the custom attribute, then you could use a built-in attribute like `name` or add a hidden `input` or `span` element with your custom data to each row/data element.

Comment: I guess having a HiddenField isn't so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a button behind the label, set `CommandName="Select"` on that button and hide it with `display:none` style. In ListView's ItemDataBound event handler you can add onmouseover attribute to label to fire those button click and handle ListView's SelectedIndexChanging event where you naturally can get selected item's index.

markup:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <li>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>' />
          <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SelectButton" CommandName="Select" style="display:none;" />
     </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code:

```
void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var label = e.Item.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        var selectButton = e.Item.FindControl("SelectButton") as Button;
        label.Attributes["onmouseover"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(selectButton, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'm going to accept that since it gets the job done. Thanks